# Can I determine the temporary path of an open excel workbook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to create an excel file from ASP.NET. I assume this file is created somewhere temporary right? How can I get this location?

Answer (score 3):

What are you using to create the Excel file? Since you have an ASP.NET tag I hope you are not trying to do this with Office COM Automation, it is not supported and trust me it is very very unreliable. See this link from Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Key message from the link

***Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.***

I would suggest that you take a look at using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) library, it is very fast and works reliably on the server side. And you can then control where the file is generated.

Comment: What I can add is that there can also be big difference between a development Environment and a productive System.

Comment: i had read this article that you gave me previously!!!im not familiar with NPOI.....is there any other solution???

Comment: @user726895, there is no solution using Office Automation that will work reliably. I would highly recommend you take a look at NPOI it is really not very difficult to get it going, it is actually simpler that wading through the automation APIs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a temp path or a temp file you should not care about where it is. If you need to care you should use a concrete path with a concrete file. You can also use a MemoryStream to do this all without HardDisk.

EDIT:
Additional to the comment I recommend you to use Open XML to create a Excel Sheet. If this is an option let me know than will I post more on that.

I must say I didn't know this article from Chris Taylors post and if I had found this one last year it had saved me a lot of time. But what I must say at this point; it is possible to get a serverside solution running which uses interop and I need it last year. But it was a pain till it work and if anyone want to give it a try here are some advices:

- you should not use interop directly
  from a ASP apllication
- you can't use impersonation (it may
  fail unexpected)
- you will need a service which runs as
  System
- you need a executable that runs the
  interop
- you have to manage the the execution
  through the service (and I mean
  manage, not just starting)

And again; I don't recommend to do this. Use any other solution if you. (MS Supports automation services with SharePoint2010)

Comment: im using Interop.Excel during which i open a workbook using 'Excelapp.workbooks.add[1]'...but on the server where exactly would it write the data???

Comment: Chris Taylor explains it all in it's post. I don't recommend the use of Interop due to permission problems on productive systems. And if you still wanna use it create a service that manages one ore more workerprocess that care about the interop.